# Is there a Custom Map to practice defending against specific cheeses?

Tags: starcraft-2

As a relatively new player (top of my bronze division)  I have to deal with learning how to counter all the popular cheeses like 6 pool.  My 2v2 partner has the same problem.  When we're both online, we can practice by me doing a 6 pool to him.  But wouldn't it be cool if he could just load up a custom map of some sort, and tell the AI to do a 6 pool?

So, has someone done this already?  Is it possible to tell the AI what build order to use when making a custom map?  I would want it to simulate a 6 pool exactly.  The end result would be something like the rush defense challenge that you can do in the single player mode, but with the exact mechanics of a 1v1 ladder game.

Perhaps there would eventually be a library of cheese maps, and everyone would learn to defend against them, and maybe that would actually force some people to stop using them so much :)

Comment: Yeah, it's called Bronze League. You'll be cheesed 5 out of 10 games. Green Tea AI does have a bunch of cheesing commanders, but you still want to practice on ladder. Knowing a cheese is coming goes a long way to defending it.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if you can tell the ai to do a build order(but i'm leaning to 'no') but maybe you can just spawn a certain number of zerglings after a certain point in time then make them attack your base? you can also force spawn buildings and a number of workers(to simulate the normal ladder game) and then leave it to the ai to carry on from there

Comment: It should be possible to let it build specific build orders as i read about maps where people let the AI do specific build orders to test for example 6-pool vs 7-pool or the use of the (double) extractor trick.