# Best strategy against Worker Rush cheese in 2v2 and other matchups

Tags: starcraft-2

So basically some players have started to just attacking with all their workers right from the beginning of the match. I have encountered this is 2v2, where it sort of works (I guess because of the fact that they have 2 sets of workers, attacking 1 player (who has 1 set of workers), at least until the second player comes up to help (if he does)). So I am not sure if this works at all in 1v1 or other matchups, but anyways.

What would be the best reaction to this?

Comment: Related Question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10283/drone-rushes-counter-for-each-race

Comment: It's called a worker rush FYI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one alternate idea. If both opponents send their workers to attack you, you can take all of your workers and go attack your opponents' (now empty) bases. Meanwhile, your teammate should build up, focusing on getting their first marine/zealot/zerglings up ASAP.

This means your opponents have to do one of the following:

- Ignore your workers, in which case your workers will kill their undefended bases.
- Follow your workers to defend their bases, in which case your ally should have MUCH more time to build up.
- Leave your base and go after your ally, in which case you return to your base and try to build up. Your ally can then do the same thing, going to attack their bases.

The main principle here is that if they both send their first 6 workers, it's going to be 12 vs 7-8 defenders, which unless you have incredible micro skills, you're going to lose. And they are going to reach you before you have any defenses, sometimes before you even have a supply depot finished. So, *do not engage*, and instead string them out until your ally can put @tenfour's advice into play: build a strong economy which will overwhelm them, since they have at most 1-2 workers at home.

Comment: I see a problem when scenario 2 happens, if you go to them and they decide to just start. Then they've put you behind... ^^

Comment: Hm, gotta try this. This may work, because the real problem is that while they are in my base, I can't mine anything, not even with 1 worker, because then he gets killed. But by moving the battle to their home, I can probably counteract this.

Comment: @TomWij I suppose, but if you attack them, and they return to defend, you can bring your workers home too. In that case both you and they are 1-2 mins behind, but your ally should be way ahead.

Comment: Ah, yeah, good idea. But can't they destroy your CC/Nexus/Hatch before you destroy theirs as they have more workers? But I suppose they are still minutes behind then, they're giving up their economy just to stop one player, but not both... :-)

Comment: I am tempted to suggest that you should just save all of your workers minus two or three that you can micro. Use the "saved" workers to distance mine. This leaves them with the choice of chasing your miners (slowing down the base attack), and engaging in micro at the same time. Either way, this will sufficiently occupy them long enough to allow your partner to arrive either at their bases or yours with strength. You want to divide their efforts as much as possible away from your destroying your main. Clumping off into two or even three (say a lone worker) is a lot to track down even for two.

Answer (score 12):

I have had this happen a couple times, and my first thought was "that is really dumb". To send all your workers at the start of the game doesn't seem to have any hope of winning. At best, you will kill one enemy but be left so vulnerable to any rushes that it won't matter. So, take advantage of that. I haven't ever seen this in a 1v1 but I similarly think that it has almost no hope of winning.

The idea here is that they sacrificed their entire economy for an attack. In a case where your enemy's economy is suffering, the principle is to stay alive as long as possible so your economic advantage will be effective, but don't wait so long that they can recover economically. In a 2v2, you have the advantage that one of you can almost die while the other builds an army.

Keep as much alive as possible for as long as possible, until your ally can come with attacking units. Don't bother trying to attack them, just run around and keep them busy. Don't even bother too much trying to mine while they're chasing you. While the enemy is picking off a few of your workers, your ally will be building an army. If it helps, send all your own resources to your ally so he can make attacking units as fast as possible. You will have a huge advantage because you have one player with full economy, so he should be able to clean up the enemy workers (or just keep them busy), and send a couple units to the enemy's certainly-empty bases to prevent any worker creation.

Your ally should keep in mind that the opponents may change their minds and start attacking him instead, since you are just running them around doing very little damage. Walling in with unfinished supply depots and barracks can help get a wall up faster. Or blocking access to the mineral line with pylons / gateway.

Keep them running around, and you will have an army before your enemy for sure.

Comment: You beat me to it. Good answer.

Comment: This sounds good, but 1) if 1 player dies to 2 sets of workers, the other won't have time to build anything until they come to him, there is no time usually 2) sending resources is not enabled until 5 minute mark or something, which is too late.

Comment: Its up to the player getting attacked to delay as long as possible.  Micro your workers around and keep kiting the attacking workers to keep yours alive as long as possible.  Generally this should give your team mate enough time to get a rax, pool, or gateway up and a few tier 1 units.  Then he can mop up the workers and immediately counter.